# Show selected text file in html page after submit button press

Tags: php, html

Good Day Everyone
Ok, so I have done as much as I understand and need some direction and help. Currently i'm very new to html/php so please bear with me. The plan is to list the text files from a Dir in a dropdown list, this I have done, now I would like to display the text file in the same page in a table upon submit button press. This is what I have so far, any input welcome as I am still learning!
The bash script is just a grep function to grab specific lines from the original file and copy it to /tmp.
Thanks Again

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Data Request</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 align="center">Dispatch Report</h1>
<h2 align="center">Wrong Arrives Report</h2>

<table align="center" border="2">
<tr>
<td>Select Shift<br>
<form name="shiftfrm" id="shiftfrm">
<select name="shiftlist" id="shiftlist">
  <option value="" selected="selected">--------</option>
<?php
$dir = opendir ("/var/www/files/");
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir))) {
            if (strpos($file, '.txt',1)) {
                echo '<option value="' . $file . '">' . $file . '</option>';
            }
    }
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>

<?php
if( ($handle = fopen( '/tmp/sh130418n.txt', 'r' )) !== false )
{
$output = '<table align="center" width="" border="2">';
while( ($data = fgetcsv( $handle )) !== false )
{
    $output .= '<tr>';
    foreach( $data as $value )
    {
        $output .= sprintf( '<td>%s</td>', $value );
    }
fclose( $handle );
$output .= '</table>';
}
echo $output;
?>

</td></tr>
</table>

<?php
$output = exec('/var/www/cgi-bin/manualexceptget.sh');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assume `<form method="post" action="">`. Augment your file reading code:

```
if(!empty($_POST['shiftlist'])) {
    $file = 'files/'.$_POST['shiftlist'];
    if(file_exists($file)) {
        if( ($handle = fopen( $file, 'r' )) !== false )
        {
            $output = '<table align="center" width="" border="2">';
            while( ($data = fgetcsv( $handle )) !== false )
            {
                $output .= '<tr>';
                foreach( $data as $value )
                {
                    $output .= '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
                }
                $output .= '</table>';
            }
            echo $output;
            fclose( $handle );
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Fixed the isset() issue stated below. Changed some code, $handle was closed before reading was finished.

Edit2: I just put this in editor and saw many html tags, that were not placed properly (e.g. form not closed). Working sample at [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/nMx9yS7m) (tested on xampp)

Comment: Since you're using `!empty` you don't need `isset`.

Comment: try using [empty](http://php.net/empty) on a variable, that doesn't exist. it'll throw an error. the [isset](http://php.net/isset) prevent this, because it ends the if statement the moment the isset function returns false.

Comment: "Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE. empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist." From the PHP manual for `empty()`. http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: Is this a question? Or a proposition?

Comment: Sorry, question! @Imperative

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this for (.txt) files..

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Data Request</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 align="center">Dispatch Report</h1>
<h2 align="center">Wrong Arrives Report</h2>

<table align="center" border="2">
<tr>
<td>Select Shift<br />
<form name="shiftfrm" id="shiftfrm" method="POST">
<select name="shiftlist" id="shiftlist">
  <option value="" selected="selected">--------</option>
<?php

$dir = opendir("files/");
while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir)))
{
    if (strpos($file, '.txt', 1))
    {
        echo '<option value="' . $file . '">' . $file . '</option>';
    }
}

?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
<br />
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['shiftlist']))
{
    if ($handle = file_get_contents('files/' . $_POST['shiftlist']))
    {
        $output = '<table align="center" width="" border="2">';
        $output .= '<tr><td>';
        echo $handle;
        $output .= '</tr></td>';
        $output .= '</table>';
    } else
    {
        echo "No Content";
    }
} else
{
    echo "Please select the file";
}

?>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: THANKS a MIL, it works, now to get the comma delimited txt file into coloums and rows, only displaying file as is. BUT i'm 1 step closer!!!

Comment: Still need some help, unable to get the files displaying in coloums, can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks @Prasath Albert